# Update AD Attribute from CSV Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying update attribute HomePage in AD from CSV file.

When i do:

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\user.domain.com\Desktop\test.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Header "AccountName" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Identity $_.AccountName
}
```

All is good.

But when i try update:

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\user.domain.com\Desktop\test.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Header "AccountName" | ForEach-Object{
    $AccountName = $_.AccountName
    $HomePage = $_.HomePage -split ';'
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_.AccountName -HomePage @{add= $_.HomePage}
}
```

Get error:

```
Set-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'AccountName' under: 'DC=domain,DC=com'.
At line:4 char:1
+ Set-ADUser -Identity $_.AccountName -HomePage @{add= $_.HomePage}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (AccountName:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Comment: PLEASE format your code properly. the instructions on how to do that are linked to the page you used to create your Question ... and the Tour page for this site.

Comment: Does the `test.csv` already contain a header row with the column names? If the answer is yes, you shouldn't specify `-Header "AccountName"`

Comment: Seems top me your csv file already has headers, at least `AccountName` and `HomePage`. Please open the csv in notepad, copy the first 3 or 4 lines, [edit] your question and paste that in.

Comment: My CSV file look like:                                                                                                               "AccountName","HomePage"
test,www
test1,www1
test2,www2